# How can I get wireless icon back without restarting computer?

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.  Every time my wireless adapter gets disconnected for any reason, say if it falls over, which it does constantly, or if I change it to an extension USB cord, the wireless icon that I use to connect to wireless goes away, and it can't be found in computer settings either.  When I reboot the computer it comes back.  But it does not cleanly shut down, the wireless adapter goes into some kind of loop I can't stop or get control away from it.

How can I recover wireless connection without rebooting the computer?

Comment: We'd have to see the log files (maybe some error?) to know for sure.  But restarting network manager might help.

Comment: How do I restart network manager?   There is no error message - just the little wireless icon disappears, and wireless cannot be found in system settings.

Comment: Sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

Comment: There's probably piles of error messages, warnings, and just general debug chatter in some file in `/var/log/` and some of it might even be relevant.

Comment: Does `iwconfig` results show power management on?